# Python - pypdf - KeyError: '/Contents'

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to extract "Content" from "Annotation" from PDF File.
Only problem is when a comment has only SPACE, it return me a KeyError: '/Contents'
do you have any clue has to solve this issue ?
May be to check if the 'content' has no alphanumeric then do something..
Thanks

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

for page in reader.pages:
    if "/Annots" in page:
        for annot in page["/Annots"]:
            subtype = annot.get_object()["/Subtype"]
            if subtype == "/Text":
                if annot.get_object()["/Contents"] ==" ":
                    print("space")
                else:
                    print(annot.get_object()["/Contents"])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmghq.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a testable pdf file that would reproduce this error ?

Comment: The example needs to be a pdf or a odt file I can convert to pdf, the image doesn't help to uderstand the file's structure.

Comment: i do not know how to had PDF file to this post. How to ?

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized it isn't supported. You could use a file transfer platform like https://www.grosfichiers.com/

Comment: if you give me an email address, yes i can put it on grosfichier.com

Comment: You don't need a real email address, just put `anything@somedomain.com` and share the link on your post

Comment: grosfi.ch/XB7nQEkfrnw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("ex.pdf")

for page in reader.pages:
    if "/Annots" in page:
        for annot in page["/Annots"]:
            subtype = annot.get_object()["/Subtype"]
            if subtype == "/Text":
                if '/Contents' in annot.get_object().keys():
                   if annot.get_object()["/Contents"] ==" ":
                       print("space")
                   else:
                        print(annot.get_object()["/Contents"])
                else:
                  print('no content in annotation')
```

Hope this helps !